# How to get the right URL from firebase storage to access my files in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

My photos are being successfully saved on my firebase storage although I just cannot access it through the formed link. When I try I receive the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

As far as I know this error can only happen if the given URL is not right. Right?

I'll share the whole fragment of my code where I save the picture on the firebase as it follows:

```
            if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
            {
                //var serviceAccountPath = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, "Credentials", "connect-vistorias-firebase-adminsdk-33gel-857c85cf70.json");
                FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
                {
                    Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()
                });
            }
                
            var bucketName = "bucketname";
            var storage = StorageClient.Create();

            #region Medidores
            if (model.Medidores != null && model.Medidores.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in model.Medidores)
                {
                    var prop = item.Id > 0 ? db.VistoriasMedidors.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == item.Id) : new VistoriasMedidor();
                    prop.Desligado = item.Desligado;
                    var listaFotos = new List<string>();


                    foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
                    {
                        if (fileName == "Medidores[" + item.Index + "].upFotos")
                        {
                            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                var fileName1 = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm}-{Guid.NewGuid()}-{file.FileName}";

                                using (var stream = file.InputStream)
                                {
                                    var objectName = $"Medidores/{fileName1}";
                                    storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, stream);

                                    var fileUrl = $"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{bucketName}/o/{objectName}?alt=media";
                                    listaFotos.Add(fileUrl);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    prop.Fotos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaFotos);
                    prop.Leitura = item.Leitura;
                    prop.Medidor = item.Medida;

                    if (prop.Id == 0)
                    {
                        prop.IdVistoria = vistoria.Id;
                        prop.IdAppInterno = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        prop.Tipo = item.Tipo;
                        db.VistoriasMedidors.Add(prop);
                        //db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (novo)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    var prop = new VistoriasMedidor();
                    prop.Desligado = true;
                    var listaFotos = new List<string>();

                    prop.Fotos = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaFotos);
                    prop.Leitura = "";
                    prop.Medidor = "";

                    if (prop.Id == 0)
                    {
                        prop.IdVistoria = vistoria.Id;
                        prop.IdAppInterno = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        prop.Tipo = i;
                        db.VistoriasMedidors.Add(prop);
                        //db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Please pay attention on how I am saving my URL:

`var fileUrl = $"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{bucketName}/o/{objectName}?     alt=media";`

Am I missing something or it is really the right way to save the URL? I know in other languages you can declare a public URL by changing the last line for:

`var fileUrl = storage.GetDownloadUrl(bucketName, objectName);`

But in .NET it is just not possible since GetDownloadUrl is not included in the firebase library. I already changed permission in the "Rules" as it follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I would be extremely thankful if anyone could point where and what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security rules are only applied when you access the data through a Firebase SDK. It seems like you want to generate a direct URL to access it, in which case the security rules are never applied.

If you have a Firebase-provided client-side SDK, you can indeed instruct it to generate a so-called **download URL**, which provides public read-only access to the file. This method does (as you found) not exist in non-Firebase SDKs, such as the [Google Cloud SDK for C#/.NET](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp).

In such platforms, your options are to:

- Make all files in the bucket publicly accessible, as shown in the documentation on [making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public). At that point the URL to access the individual files will look similar to what you've created above.
- Generate a signed URL for each file, which is similar to a download URL, but provides public access for a defined time period (which can be as long as you want). For more on this, see the documentation on [Creating a GET-signed URL for an object using Cloud Storage libraries (V4)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-signed-url-v4), which also contains a code sample in C#.